# Exception while reading value directly from the URL without embedding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a ASP.NET MVC 4 project, I have simple function as :

```
   public string chk(int tmp)
    {
          string message = "Stoe.Brose, Genre =" + tmp;
            return message;
    }
```

I am getting the tmp value from url as : `http://localhost:55142/store/chk/8`

Instead of getting the value displayed in the browser I am getting **exception** as :

```
    The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'tmp' 
of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String chk(Int32)'
 in 'MvcApplication3.Controllers.StoreController'. An optional parameter must
 be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

Complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        public string chk(int tmp)
        {
              string message = "Stoe.Brose, Genre =" + tmp;
                return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might also be helpful to see how your routing is configured. (Usually in `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder).

Comment: Its my first program in ASP.NET. So rest all are the same code that's been created by VS 2013. I have not changed anything else. Besides I am able to display string values when I change the parameter to `string type` and in the URL I type as : `http://localhost:55142/store/chk/xyz`

Comment: Try changing `public string chk(int tmp)` to `public string chk(int? tmp)`.

Comment: the exception has gone but still I can't see the number i.e, 8

Comment: Instead of `tmp`, change it to `id`, which is probably the default configured in `RouteConfig.cs` and why I asked for it.

Comment: @mason : yes its working now. Actually in case of string I was able to give any variable name. So I thought for int also I can give any name. but I was wrong can you please explain the behavior once. for string I typed something like `http://localhost:55142/store/chk?tmp=xyz` and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route configuration (`~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`) you have this line:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This tells the routing system where to pull the parameters from. Notice that after the action, you are telling it `id`, and telling it that it's an optional parameter. But in your controller you're expecting `tmp`. There are four solutions:

---

Change your controller to expect `id` instead of `tmp`, and make `id` nullable.

```
public string chk(int? id)
{
    string message = "Stoe.Brose, Genre =" + id;
    return message;
}
```

---

Change routing to expect `tmp` and make `tmp` nullable.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{tmp}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", tmp = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

public string chk(int? tmp)
   {
       string message = "Stoe.Brose, Genre =" + tmp;
       return message;
   }
```

---

Or pass `tmp` via query string

```
/store/chk?tmp=5
```

and make it nullable.

```
public string chk(int? tmp)
{
    string message = "Stoe.Brose, Genre =" + tmp;
    return message;
}
```

---

You can also use [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) to tell it how to map the parameters. Note that attribute routing is only available in MVC 5 and above.

```
[Route("chk/{tmp}")]
public string chk(int? tmp)
    {
        string message = "Stoe.Brose, Genre =" + tmp;
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: I checked all the solution and its working fine. Can you please explain why in case of string parameter I did not face this issue? I just kept on changing the name of variable and it worked.

Comment: @Unbreakable String isn't nullable. It'll just be empty. Therefore it doesn't need to throw an exception.

Comment: Without incorporating any of the solution that you mentioned above when I  passed string parameter and gave URL as 'http://localhost:55142/store/chk?tmp=xyz' I was able to see `xyx` text in browser

Comment: That's because you passed `tmp` via query string and didn't need to change string to nullable, because the compiler knows that if `tmp` is missing it can just use an empty string, thus no compilation exception. If you had passed tmp like this: `/store/chk/xyz` the system would have thought that `xyz` was `id`, not `tmp` and then (assuming your action method signature is `public string chk(string tmp)` then `tmp` would be empty.

Comment: I totally got your point. many many thanks. :) Actually its my first ASP.NET MVC 4 program

Comment: @Unbreakable It all comes down to setting up your routes to match the parameters in your action methods. The parameter names need to match in order for it to automatically map the URL segment to the correct parameter, or you have to explicitly tell if via key/value pair (query string) which value should be matched to which parameter.

Comment: @Unbreakable I thought of a 4th solution based on attribute routing and added it to my answer. I personally use attribute routing, as I like to have my routes right next to my functions.